# How do I set environment variables in an Emacs session launched from Gnome Panel?

Tags: gnome-panel, bash, emacs

My `.bash_env` file sets several environment variables, including `PATH` and `EMAIL`, but in an Emacs session launched from the Gnome Panel (command: "`/usr/bin/emacs23 %F`") these variables do not have the expected values. I've run into this problem before (see [this blog post](http://procrastiblog.com/2007/07/09/changing-your-path-in-emacs-compilation-mode/)). I fixed it then by sourcing `.bash_env` in my `.xsession` file. Obviously, this is no longer working.

The variables are set properly if I manually launch Emacs from a terminal. Oddly, they aren't set if I change the panel launcher to execute Emacs in a terminal (I would think this would start Bash before starting Emacs).

How can I make sure the regular Bash environment is set up for the Emacs session?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the environment variables in `~/.profile` (and source `~/.profile` from `~/.xsession` if you use a `.xsession`). That way they will be available everywhere, because they'll be set when you log in.

`~/.bash_env` is not the right place for environment variables (despite the name) . (Despite its existence (that's `$BASH_ENV`, right?) I've yet to find a good use for it.)

When you run Emacs in a terminal, it is a subprocess of the terminal emulator. There would be no reason to have a shell in between.

Comment: As noted, I source `~/.bash_env` from `~/.xsession`. I don't see any reason `~/.profile` should be any different.

Comment: @Chris: How do you log in: which display manager (gdm, kdm, …) and which session type? And what release of Ubuntu do you use? Are you sure your `.xsession` is actually used (that's hard to achieve on 10.04)?

Comment: I use gdm to log into GNOME on Ubuntu 10.04. I'm not sure that .xsession is being used (not since I upgraded to 10.04, at least; it used to be).

Comment: @Chris: With this setup, `.xsession` is not used. It's only used if you select a custom session, and gdm on Ubuntu 10.04 doesn't offer one (the Ubuntu folks blame the Gnome folks and vice versa). But `~/.profile` is read no matter what session you choose.

Comment: .profile does the trick!

Answer (score 1):

`/usr/bin/zsh -c emacs` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just add bash to your launcher command, like `bash codecodecode emacs %stuff` (aka, just add bash at the beginning of the line) and it should work.

Comment: "bash emacs %F" gives "/usr/bin/emacs: cannot execute binary file". "bash -c 'emacs %F'" doesn't set the environment variables.